Why is Elasticsearch not using analyzer tokens during search?
index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "autocomplete",
  "field": "name",
  "text": "жаб"
  
}

gives me correct tokens:
{
    "tokens": [{
        "token": "žab",
        "start_offset": 0,
        "end_offset": 3,
        "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
        "position": 0
    }]
}

now when i plugin in token žab into search it works, it is giving me the results.
Explain query:
index/_validate/query?explain
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "жаб"
    }
  }
}

is giving me
{
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "valid": true,
    "explanations": [
        {
            "index": "places_for_search",
            "valid": true,
            "explanation": "name:žab"
        }
    ]
}

so it is converted into žab.
but when i have
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "жаб"
    }
  }
}

it does not give me any results but it should, since žab gives me results.
i even tried forcing analyzer like this:
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "жаб",
      "type": "bool_prefix",
      "fields": [
        "name"
      ],
      "analyzer": "autocomplete"
    }
  }
}

but still, no results.
Just for sake of argument my document looks like:
{
   "id": "ChIJT3DV8zM5TRMRlVS4y79AH7A",
    "name": "Žabljak"
}

field name has autocomplete analyzer:
{
    "type": "search_as_you_type",
     "doc_values": false,
     "max_shingle_size": 3,
     "analyzer": "autocomplete",
     "search_analyzer": "autocomplete"
}

Edit: added analyzer and filters setup
My analyzer:
{
  "analyzer": {
    "autocomplete": {
      "filter": [
        "autocomplete",
        "trim",
        "asciifolding",
        "lowercase",
        "serbian_stemmer",
        "russian_stemmer"
      ],
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "standard"
    }
  }
}

My filters
{
  "filter": {
    "russian_stemmer": {
      "type": "stemmer",
      "language": "russian"
    },
    "autocomplete": {
      "type": "edge_ngram",
      "min_gram": "3",
      "max_gram": "15"
    },
    "serbian_stemmer": {
      "type": "stemmer",
      "language": "serbian"
    }
  }
}

So, bottom line, the analyzer works, but its tokens are not being used in the query. Any idea how to debug this further?

Elasticsearch uses analyzer for both search and indexing.
According to example you shared, due to your analyzer жаб converted to žab during indexing. This of course also applies during search. when you search жаб it will search for žab in the indexed data.
Check the following _analyze API call result.
POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "autocomplete",
  "text": "Žabljak"
}

Did you see žab in the response as "token": "žab"? If not it can't match...
Let's debug:

_analyze both raw data and search pattern.
žab is not equal to Žab use lowercase tokenfilter if needed.
ngram or edge_ngram tokenizer can help to tokenize Žabljak to => žab, abl, blj ...


Lower case token filter is included already. It is not that. Look at Edit: added analyzer and filters setup.

I'm unsure about the exact issue with using the stemmer type for language in this solution. It seems only an Elasticsearch expert could provide insight. However, after extensive trial and error, I've managed to configure an analyzer that effectively addresses the problem.
POST index/_settings
{
  "analysis": {
    "filter": {
      "russian_stemmer": {
        "type": "snowball",
        "language": "Russian"
      },
      "searbian_stemmer": {
        "type": "snowball",
        "language": "Russian"
      },
      "cyrillic_to_latin": {
        "type": "icu_transform",
        "id": "Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII"
      },
      "autocomplete": {
        "type": "edge_ngram",
        "min_gram": "3",
        "max_gram": "15"
      }
    },
    "analyzer": {
      "cyrillic_stemmed_transliterator": {
        "filter": [
          "autocomplete",
          "lowercase",
          "cyrillic_to_latin",
          "russian_stemmer",
          "searbian_stemmer",
          "lowercase",
          "asciifolding"
        ],
        "tokenizer": "standard"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST index/_mappings
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "search_as_you_type",
      "analyzer": "cyrillic_stemmed_transliterator"
    }
  }
}

Now if you have doc like
{
   "id": "ChIJT3DV8zM5TRMRlVS4y79AH7A",
    "name": "Žabljak"
}

and you do your search as:
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "жаб", // no matter what you put in here, zab or žab, or жаб
      "type": "bool_prefix",
      "fields": [
        "name"
      ]
    }
  }
}

you will get correct document.
Purpose of this answer and above question:
If you have property names written in Latin characters but you want to search for them using Cyrillic letters or ascii, you're essentially seeking a way to seamlessly bridge the two character sets for effective search functionality.
